# CLion build depend targets

Tags: cmake, clion

My CLions CMakeLists.txt contains more than 1 target (libraries and depends executables). 
How can I configure building all targets in one click, instead of choosing target one by one and building them? 
For example, in Visual Studio I can configure project dependencies and build all solution. CLions "Edit configurations..."->"Before launch:Build" won't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the command [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) to your `CMakeLists.txt`, it does what you want:

> Make a top-level target depend on other top-level targets to ensure
>   that they build before  does.

Then you just need to create a *"BUILD_ALL"* target that depends on every other target.

Comment: so what would your CMakeLists.txt file look like? sorry this doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Clion use cmake right? you can directly edit the cmake file. Check add_subdirectory command.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

Answer (score -2):

Configuring target dependencies works, but it is much easier to add an "all" to CLion's build options.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with _add an "all"_? @MatzZze

Comment: Answer is too vague.  Answering MatzZze's question would go a long way.

Comment: Pardon, that should be "answering nburk's question".