# In CLion/CMake on Windows, how does APP.exe find lib/A.dll in order to run?

Tags: dll, cmake, clion

I have a CLion/CMake project that needs an external DLL, `A.dll`, which I have placed in the project `lib/` directory.  After building the executable, when I run the `APP.exe`, it cannot find/use the `lib/A.dll`.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you move the executable file after build succeed?

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't add .dll file to cmake file this is [Quick CMake Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#d93235e400)
or [CLion and CMake: only building a library without an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355937/clion-and-cmake-only-building-a-library-without-an-executable)

Comment: I am aware of the tutorial and did add the .dll but apparently I didn't not use the right command.  I used a command that apparently is good at the compilation linking step, but not at the runtime step, e.g., when you press Run in CLion.

Comment: I'm not trytng to build a library without an executable.  I'm trying to run an executable that uses an external .dll I want this project to find when I press Run in CLion.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just add D:/path/to/lib/A.dll to the Path, either globally by editing the user or system environment variables, or by creating a small batch file which sets up the Path along with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH et al then possibly spawns something like cmake-gui.exe or devenv.exe.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking [import exist lib in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44014548/1278112),this link can be help.
you may need this code in your `CMakeList.txt`

```
# Create an IMPORTED library 
add_library(A IMPORTED)
# Set IMPORTED_LOCATION *property* for this target
set_target_properties(SimpleAmqpClient PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/A.dll)
# Then use library *target* for linking with
target_link_libraries(APP PUBLIC A)
```