# cmake import exist SimpleAmqp library

Tags: windows, cmake, rabbitmq

Now my CMakeList.txt looking like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(RabbitMQClient)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
include_directories(src)
include_directories(dependentFile)
add_executable(RabbitMQClient ${SOURCE_FILES})
find_library(SimpleAmqpClient SimpleAmqpClient.2.lib PATHS ./SimpleAmqpClientLib/SimpleAmqpClient.2.lib)
set(IMPORTED_IMPLIB ./SimpleAmqpClientLib)
target_link_libraries(RabbitMQClient PUBLIC SimpleAmqpClient)
```

when Linking the RabbitMQClient it complains.

> cannot find `-lSimpleAmqpClient`

I want to use the `SimpleAmqpClient` library in the project,however not quite familiar with `cmake` not sure the `find_library`,`IMPORTED_IMPLIB`,`PUBLIC` in `target_link_libraries` was correctly used.Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have messed up with *variables*, *targets* and *properties*.

Proper usage of IMPORTED libraries for linking would be:

```
# This command sets *variable* SimpleAmqpClient_LIBRARY
find_library(SimpleAmqpClient_LIBRARY SimpleAmqpClient.2.lib
    PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SimpleAmqpClientLib # Specify a *directory*, not a library *file*
)
# Next, create an IMPORTED *target*
add_library(SimpleAmqpClient SHARED IMPORTED)
# And set IMPORTED_LIB *property* for this target
set_target_properties(SimpleAmqpClient PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LIB ${SimpleAmqpClient_LIBRARY})
# Then use library *target* for linking with
target_link_libraries(RabbitMQClient PUBLIC SimpleAmqpClient)
```

However, there some simplifications which could be done:

1. Normally, `find_library` is used when you don't know *complete path* to the library file. E.g., its *directory* may be different on different machines, or its *prefix*/*extension* may be different on different plaforms.

   If you know complete path to the library, just use this path directly (e.g., assign it to the variable).
2. Normally, property *IMPORTED_LOCATION* is used for specify library to link with. Property *IMPORTED_LIB* is specific for Windows `.dll`s, when linking requires not a library file (`.dll`), but some other one (`.lib`).

   However, CMake perfectly understands `.lib` file in *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property even for Windows `.dll`s, so your code need not distinguish *SHARED* Windows libraries from others: just use *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property in all cases.

**Simplified** version of the code:

```
# Create an IMPORTED library *target*
add_library(SimpleAmqpClient IMPORTED)
# Set IMPORTED_LOCATION *property* for this target
set_target_properties(SimpleAmqpClient PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SimpleAmqpClientLib/SimpleAmqpClient.2.lib)
# Then use library *target* for linking with
target_link_libraries(RabbitMQClient PUBLIC SimpleAmqpClient)
```

Comment: After the simplified version `add_library(SimpleAmqpClient IMPORTED)` add `STATIC` it works fine.Thank you!

Comment: after cmake config pass, linking issue error `undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10AmqpClient`.Is the problem on cmake config?

Comment: This looks like **incompatibility** between precompiled library and compiler/linker used for compile the application.

Comment: Yes,the precompiled library was built by msvc and the current project is using mingw. How do you diagnose that?