# How to use CLION create library convenient (like by click run button)?

Tags: clion

I'am using clion with lots of sub project(exe or lib), it's structure like below:

[image]

As to exe(core CMakeList as below), I can click the button `run`, then it runs as below:

```
add_executable(cv_knn_demo knn_kdtree_demo.cpp)
```

[image]

But as to library(core CMakeList as below), I can't create library by click the run button(I have to create it like normal cmake project: to mkdir build, and then cmake ..), I know library can't run(just show create exe it convenient by clion, but create library is not)

```
add_library(demo5 SHARED ${SRC_LIST})
```

[image]

How to create library by clion convenient(no need to do `mkdir build; cmake..`, just by a click)? my question is not like this: [CLion and CMake: only building a library without an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355937/clion-and-cmake-only-building-a-library-without-an-executable)

Comment: You can't *run* a library, it just doesn't make any sense. Only "programs" can *run*. So if you want to test the functions in a library, you need to make a program (`add_executable`) that uses the library.

Comment: I know, but my question means use clion to create library convenient like click a run button.

Comment: If you just want to create a brand new library project, go to the `File` menu and select `New project...`. Then you will get a dialog where you can select C++ or C library projects. Then you program your library and *build* it. That's it. No messing around with the `Run` dialog since you're not supposed to *run* anything.

Comment: Dose you mean if a clion project with many project(both exe and library), it can't create library convenient (but exe can)?
If I want to create library convenient like a click,it should be a single library project?

Comment: If you have an existing project, you don't create executable sub-project using the `Run` dialog either! You need to manually edit your `CMakeLists.txt` files. The `Run` settings dialog is only to actually *run* programs, it has nothing to do with creating projects, sub-projects or building.

Comment: I have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have know how to create it, for example the project `demo5` is used to create library.

First, choose demo5(the right rectangle in the below image)

Second, Run->build

[image]

Output as below:

[image]